# Is there a difference in calling SomeEventHandler.Invoke() vs SomeEventHandler()?

Tags: c#

Let's say that you have a C# class with the following event defined:

`public event EventHandler SomeEvent;`

Is there a difference in behavior of these two methods of invoking the event?

```
SomeEvent.Invoke(this, null); // 1
SomeEvent(this, null);        // 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

```
SomeEvent(this, null);
```

is changed to

```
SomeEvent.Invoke(this, null);
```

at compile time by the compiler.

Comment: I've read it not long ago in "C# in a nutshell", don't know if I can find it on MSDN. But I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler will translate `SomeEvent()` to `SomeEvent.Invoke()`